# JMeter: Can I create a "universal" counter that is updated across runs & saves?

Tags: jmeter

I need to create unique user names in JMeter. Can I create an ever increasing counter that only increments once each time I run the test that is persistent across saves?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, simple, just use the `__time` function to generate the current time in milliseconds and use that as the unique part of the username.